# Searching for a checkbox in the CheckBoxList VB.net

Tags: .net, search, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am making a Windows Form(Desktop Window) using vb.net where I have a TextBox at the top and a CheckBoxList below that. Now I want to search for a particular checkbox in the CheckBoxList using the value in the textbox. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **sort** the data before putting it into the CheckListBox. Now if we store all the items of the CheckListBox in an ArrayList(or Dictionary) then the task becomes very easy. Just loop through all items in the ArrayList(or Dictionary) and stop where you find the value in the ArrayList(or Dictionary) that **starts with** the value in the TextBox used for searching. Do this process on **TextChanged** event of TextBox. Having found the index now simply change the selected index of CheckListBox to the index found. Here is my code.

```
    Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim iIndex As Integer = 0
    Try
        For Each key In gDict.Keys
            If key.ToUpper.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper) Then
                CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = iIndex
                Exit For
            End If
            iIndex += 1
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TP Designer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

PS : Don't forget to sort the data that you are putting in the CheckListBox